# IResultFilter not consistently writing response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1

I have the following code:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {            
        services.AddMvc().AddMvcOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new MessageAttribute("This is the Globally-Scoped Filter"));
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
}

public class MessageAttribute : ResultFilterAttribute
{
    private string message;
    public MessageAttribute(string msg)
    {
        message = msg;
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        WriteMessage(context, $"<div>Before Result:{message}</div>");
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {
        WriteMessage(context, $"<div>After Result:{message}</div>");
    }

    private void WriteMessage(FilterContext context, string msg)
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"<div>{msg}</div>");
        context.HttpContext.Response.Body.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
}

[Message("This is the Controller-Scoped Filter", Order = 10)]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Message("This is the First Action-Scoped Filter", Order = 1)]
    [Message("This is the Second Action-Scoped Filter", Order = -1)]
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View("Message", $"This is the {nameof(Index)} action on the {nameof(HomeController)}");
    }
}
```

When I hit the `Index()` action method. I get one of these 3 outputs:

1)

```
Before Result:This is the Second Action-Scoped Filter
Before Result:This is the Globally-Scoped Filter
Before Result:This is the First Action-Scoped Filter
Before Result:This is the Controller-Scoped Filter
After Result:This is the Controller-Scoped Filter
After Result:This is the First Action-Scoped Filter
After Result:This is the Globally-Scoped Filter
After Result:This is the Second Action-Scoped Filter
```

2. 

```
Before Result:This is the Second Action-Scoped Filter
Before Result:This is the Globally-Scoped Filter
Before Result:This is the First Action-Scoped Filter
Before Result:This is the Controller-Scoped Filter
```

3. 

A blank page

When the page loads, it is usually 2), however sometimes it's 3). After a refresh it sometimes gives me 1), but continuously refreshing the page gives me random results, favouring 2) and 3).

If I put a breakpoint in `WriteMessage()`, let it break, and then continue the execution, it gives the expected 1) output.

Why is this inconsistent behaviour happening?

Comment: You may need to Flush() the message buffer.  Timers are used ins streams to move data from a temporary buffer to the output.

Comment: I can't repro this (though I'm using .NET Core 3.1). I would suggest using the async version of this code though. So override [`OnResultExecutionAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.resultfilterattribute.onresultexecutionasync?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Filters_ResultFilterAttribute_OnResultExecutionAsync_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Filters_ResultExecutingContext_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Filters_ResultExecutionDelegate_) and use `context.HttpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Adam Freeman, the author of Pro ASP.NET Core MVC 2, where I got the code snippets from:

> In 2.0, responses were not written until all of the components in the
> pipeline have processed the request. In 2.1, that changed so that the
> response is written as soon as content is produced. When you try to
> add to the body, ASP.NET Core gets confused because it needs to update
> the Content-Length header but can't because the response is being
> written out already.
>
> The inconsistent results appear because you have created a race
> condition. Sometimes your filters get to modify the response before a
> thread is allocated to write it out, sometimes not.
> You can either use the version of ASP.NET Core specified in the book or update your code so that it doesn't try to modify the response after the action method renders its view.

Comment: It seems like upgrading is the correct approach because this is a straight up bug

Comment: @AluanHaddad do you mean downgrading? I am getting this error because I'm using 2.1 instead of 2.0.